# Passing Env Variables from GitHub action to json

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I want to pass the env variable from GitHub Action to my config.json file, How to pass the env variables to json file.

In GitHub action secret, I have set `Node_Server_Url` one of my IP address.

Config.json

```
{
  "SERVER_URL": "https://{ip}:9000",
}
```

Comment: You cannot use variables inside JSON. Either generate the JSON dynamically so that you can inject the variable or use the variable directly in the code where you need the JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could edit your config json files adding this step:

```
  - name: "inject server ip"
    env:
      server_ip: ${{ secrets.Node_Server_Url }}
    run: |
      sed -i "s/{ip}/$server_ip/g" config.json
```